# Apply color to ActionLink

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I am trying to change the font of a `ActionLink`, however I cannot get it to change when I have `, null` at the end of it.

What I have tried:

```
@Html.ActionLink(" Verification |", "VerIndex", "MFC_Form", new { deviceID = item.DeviceID, type = "Verification", id = "Color" }, null)

window.onload = function () {
    var x = "fontColor";
    alert("color " + x);
    if (x == "fontColor") {
        $("#Color").css('color', "red");
    }
    else {
        $("#Color").css('color', "green");
    }
}
```

and

```
@Html.ActionLink(" Verification |", "VerIndex", "MFC_Form", new { deviceID = item.DeviceID, type = "Verification", style = "color:red" }, null)
```

and

```
@Html.ActionLink(" Verification |", "VerIndex", "MFC_Form", new { deviceID = item.DeviceID, type = "Verification", @class = "fontColor" }, null)
```

Comment: Why don't you add a class to the `ActionLink` and apply the desired style via your CSS file instead of JavaScript?

Comment: I tried that with the last two tries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix the `routeValues` and `htmlAttributes` parameters. These two must be distinct objects.

**View**

```
@Html.ActionLink(" Verification |", "VerIndex", "MFC_Form", new {deviceID = item.DeviceID, type = "Verification"}, new { @class = "text-red" })
```

**CSS**

```
.text-red {
    color: red;
}
```

The generated link looks like this:

```
<a class="text-red" href="/MFC_Form/VerIndex?deviceID=1&type=Verification"> Verification |</a>
```